# I have tried to set my ViewController3 as rootVC for my logged in users and vc for non logged in, but instead it turns black

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, authentication, rootviewcontroller

When I tried it out on my Iphone, and instead of showing VC3 or VC, my rootVC was completely black and I don't know how to get VC3 and VC instead depending on if the user is logged in.. Have tried self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red but my simulator doesn't respond to the code

Thank you in advance and sorry if it's a stupid question but I am new to this.

```
 AppDelegate

    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "ViewController3", bundle: nil)
    var initialViewController = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Onboarding")
    let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
    if userDefaults.bool(forKey: "LoginComplete") {
        initialViewController = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController3")
    }
    window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()


ViewController3


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

       infoView.isHidden = true

        let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
        userDefaults.set(true, forKey: "LoginComplete")
        userDefaults.synchronize()
```

}

Comment: Cast the view controller to the appropriate view controller class.  instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Onboarding") as Onboarding (or whatever your view controller class is called)

Comment: @MatthewBradshaw I want the non logged in users to go to ViewController and the logged in to ViewController3, but I don't no how to do what you wrote above..

Comment: This should work !! ,I can see no major reasons that your code is not working, Try to create another sample view controller inside your storyboard named **ViewController3**  and try to show this

Comment: Wait, I may have found the problem! I think I put the coding from AppDelegate in the wrong class. But I am unsure of which I should put it in.. Now the code is in "didFinishLaunchingWithOptions" @PrashantTukadiya

Comment: I also get this  'Could not find a storyboard named 'ViewController3' in bundle @PrashantTukadiya